# How to set variables in php using JSON array

Tags: php, json, rest, api

Hi this is the deepest I have ever dove into PHP because today I started using `curl` to access the **Proofhub** REST API. I have managed to get the data I wanted from the API but now I want to use that data to create a dashboard.

I want to use the file I created with the JSON array to set variables in PHP. Variables like `id` `name`, variables that correspond to the data I have in the JSON array.

#### Section of JSON Array file:

```
{
"id": 896585647,
"title": "Butterfly Scheme Project",
"description": null,
"color": "#B200FF",
"start_date": "2016-06-08",
"end_date": null,
"template": false,
"sample_project": false,
"status": {
  "id": 262601041
},
"favourite": false,
"favourite_sort": null,
"import_id": 0,
"assigned": [
  1228530673,
  1228517105,
  1228625654,
  2004959642,
  1228503536
],
"category": {
  "id": 665985348
},
"creator": {
  "id": 1228530673
},
"manager": {
  "id": 1228530673
},
"created_at": "2016-06-08T09:51:52+00:00",
"updated_at": "2018-02-15T11:25:12+00:00"
}
```

I understand that I may have to use `include` or `file_get_contents` to acheive this, but I just don't know how. I hope you can help.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? the code you are using to fetch the file at least? post it in the question by editing it.

Comment: You are looking for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: You'll want to do `json_decode(file_get_contents('blah.json'), true);`